# PanDoc - How to insert variables in header in docx with pandoc_title_block extension?

Tags: yaml, markdown, docx, pandoc

I would like to generate a DOCX with a variables inside header based on the texts inserted in the md file as variables, such as the title of the document, the version and the date of publication.

Through the `yaml_metadata_block` extension and the creation of custom fields in the `reference.docx` file I was able but I would like not to use form fields.

I understand (but I could be wrong) that with the extension `pandoc_title_block` this can be done but I don't understand how it works and I don't find examples on the net that I can study.

- is what I said correct?
- if so, could a simple example be shared that you can study and understand?

thank you